# Check if a key is pressed two times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a function once a key is pressed more than one time. How can I do that in JavaScript?

I was thinking something like

```
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {
           alert("pressed two times");
      }
}
```

Comment: You can't do it synchronously like that. Since there is no doublekeypress event, you must detect it yourself by remembering the last key press and the time it was pressed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - Check if key was pressed twice within 5 secs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820862/javascript-check-if-key-was-pressed-twice-within-5-secs)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the time btw the key pressings, store last press in a variable and compare:

```
var lastKeyCode;
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      if (e.keyCode == lastKeyCode;) {
           alert("pressed two times");
      } else {
           lastKeyCode = e.keyCode;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define a global var and do like this

```js
var pressCount = 0; // global
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
  pressCount++;
  if (pressCount == 2) {
    alert("pressed two times");
  }
}
```

Comment: And reset `pressCount` to `0` inside `if (pressCount == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check key pressed two times in a whole word or sentence then put each key code into array and match at every time with array elements if exist mean it pressed two times.

```
var KeyCodes;
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      if (jQuery.inArray( e.keyCode, KeyCodes)) {
           //mean two time exist
      } else {
           KeyCodes.push(e.keyCode);
      }
}
```